# Deadlock in update query

Tags: stored-procedures, ssis, deadlock

I have a update query in a stored procedure which is the main reason for causing deadlock.

This stored procedure is used in SSIS package in a `foreach` loop.
It looks like that the stored procedure calls the `Salespreprocessing` table and goes into deadlock state. This occurs when we make a call to this SSIS package simultaneously. Here is my SQL query

```
UPDATE SPP  
SET SPP.Promotion_Id = T.PromotionID    
FROM staging.SalesPreProcessing SPP WITH(INDEX(staging_CIDXSalesPreprocessing1)) 
INNER JOIN #WithConcatenatedPromotionID T  
ON SPP.DocLineNo = T.BillItem  
AND SPP.DocNum = T.BillNumber  
AND SPP.Cust_Code = T.CustomerCode  
AND SPP.ZCS_EAN_CODE = T.ProductCode 
AND SPP.BILLING_REPORTING_DATE = T.PricingDate  
WHERE SPP.InterfaceStatusTrackingID = @in_InterfaceStatusTrackingId AND SPP.setupid=@in_SetupId
```

I have created clustered index for `setupid` and a non-clustered indexes for rest of the columns of the table.

Here is my non-clustered Index

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [staging_CIDXSalesPreprocessing] on salespreprocessing
(
    [SetupId] ASC,
    [InterfaceStatusTrackingID] ASC
) INCLUDE`enter code here`
([DocLineNo]  ,
    [DocNum]  ,
    [Cust_Code]  ,
    [ZCS_EAN_CODE]  ,
    [Billing_Reporting_Date]          
)
```

I am still getting Deadlock

Comment: why don't use nolock hint in tables and try?

Comment: @bmsqldev: As per my understanding we cannot apply NOLOCK for the table which we are trying to update.So in my set of lines we have one physical table which we are updating and another is temp table,so it makes no sense to put NOLOCK for temp table.Correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the non-clustered index seems pointless as its first column is setupId which you say is the column for the clustered index. Thus, assuming that the setupId values are sufficiently variegated, queries will always use the clustered index over and above the nonclustered one. What is the primary key?

In terms of avoiding the deadlock you need to:

1) Ensure that the locks are taken in the same order each time that the SP is called within the foreach loop. I don't know what you're looping round? The results of another SP/query? If so ensure that there is an `ORDER BY` in that.

2) Is the `foreach` loop within a transaction? If it is does it need to be? Could you release the locks after each call to the SP by calling it from a non-transactional environment?

3) Take as few locks as possible within the SP. I can't see what query is used to create the temporary table you join to but that may be the issue. You need to use SQL Profiler to find out what object exactly the deadlock is occurring on but using hints such as `ROWLOCK` may help.

Comment: I am getting the  following error: "The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly. While I am trying to run this particular stored procedure

Comment: To add above my SPP.BILLING_REPORTING_DATE = T.PricingDate  is actually like this CONVERT(DATETIME,SPP.BILLING_REPORTING_DATE,103) = T.PricingDate  in Update query